# checkbox rendering in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, html

[image: checkbox rendering in internet explorer]

above is the attached image of checkbox rendering in internet explorer 8.

the code used is   `<asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="selectCheckBox" />`

while it renders perfectly in Firefox and in chrome the checkbox cannot be checked, any help would be better solving this rendering problem in different browsers.
thanks.

Comment: have you tried <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="selectCheckBox"></asp:CheckBox> ?

Comment: This shouldn't be a .net issue. .NET will render the proper markup regardless of browser. Do you have any JavaScript or CSS that changes the appearance or behavior of checkboxes? I would start by stripping those away to find out what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

You did not define `Text` of checkbox.

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="selectCheckBox" runat="server" Text="Label" Checked="False" OnCheckedChanged="selectCheckBoxChanged" />
```